# ng-click does nothing, DOM notices a click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to set up a simple ng-click event, and reading through other pages about it. It seems like as long as it is added to $scope it should work, but of the two examples I have put in the below page nothing works (except the preventDefault()).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ng-click test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/DBFScube.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="DBFScube" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="zoom-controll"><li class="full"><a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $scope.growpane('I am a little thing that needs to do somethign');">Full-screen</a></li></div>
    <button ng-click="$scope.alert('I am a little thing that needs to do somethign');">Click Me</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And the controller

```
var DBFScube = angular.module("DBFScube", ['ngSanitize']);

DBFScube.controller("AppCtrl", function ($sce, $scope, $http, $filter){
    var app = this;
    //
    //$http.get("http://localhost:3000").success(function(CubeSides){
      //  app.CubeSides = CubeSides;
    //})
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000").success(function(CubeSides){
        $scope.sides=CubeSides;
        console.log("Loading data");
    })
    app.getmenuname = function(side) {
        if($scope.sides === undefined) {
            console.log("Not loaded fside " + side );
        } else {
            console.log("Got menu pane " + $scope.sides);
            var fside = $filter('filter')($scope.sides, function (d) {return d.side === side;})[0];
            console.log("Sending: " + fside.menuname);
            return fside.menuname;
        }
    }
    $scope.alert = function(message) { alert(message); }
    $scope.growpane = function (side) {
        console.log("You pressed the button, like " + side);
    }
    app.showpane = function (side) {
        console.log("Loading side: " + side);
        if($scope.sides === undefined) {
            console.log("Not loaded yet");
        } else {
            console.log("Got page " + $scope.sides);
            var fside = $filter('filter')($scope.sides, function (d) {return d.side === side;})[0];
            var culine = '<iframe src="' + fside.surl + '" height="700" width="700"></iframe>';
            console.log(culine);
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(culine);
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you should not write `$scope` in the view. This holds true to everything you need from the controller, you never need to write $scope since you are in the scope of your defined controller.

Your issue is here:

```
 <button ng-click="$scope.alert('I am a little thing that needs to do somethign');">Click Me</button>
```

Change to:

```
 <button ng-click="alert('I am a little thing that needs to do somethign');">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: To add to the 2 answers saying don't use $scope in your view...I'd also recommend changing that function's name. Something about overriding alert doesn't feel right.

Comment: @dubhov I conquer. vrghost Try to keep original names to built in javascript functions.

Comment: I will be perfectly honest here, the button was just put there to see if I could get the ng-click to work in any way shape or form, and as I did not get any error message anywhere, I thought that maybe it was in one way or other related to li or a. It is only the first one that will be used, and it does now work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

$scope is not necessary inside 'ng-' attribute. Try

```
<button ng-click="alert('I am a little thing that needs to do somethign');">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ng-click test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/DBFScube.js"></script
  <script>
    module.angular("DBFScube").controller("AppCtrl",['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.someFun = function(){
      alert('I am a little thing that needs to do somethign');
    }
    }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="DBFScube" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
  <div id="zoom-controll"><li class="full"><a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $scope.growpane('I am a little thing that needs to do somethign');">Full-screen</a></li></div>
  <button ng-click="someFun()">Click Me</button>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```